# Android Google Sign-In fails on App Bundles

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I am trying to use app bundles for my app. I have enrolled into App Signing by Google and went over all the steps. While I was testing the build generated from App Bundles, I see Google Sign-In feature fails and there are no error logs to help me debug. Everything works fine on .apk. Has anyone else encountered this while using app bundles?

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

When you configure Google Sign-In, you need to go to the Google API Console and set the credentials of your Android application, which includes a SHA1 of the certificate of your application.

Instead of putting the SHA1 of the certificate that you upload your APK (or App Bundle) with, you should put the SHA1 of the App Signing certificate (i.e. what is served through the Play Store). You can find this information in the **App Integrity** page in the Play Console:

[image: App Signing screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using the same certificate for upload and app signing and hence SHA-1 of the certificate has been configured with Google API console.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Save my life. You need to add SHA-1 generated by keystore for apk and SHA-1 from Play Console for App Bundle.

Answer (score 3):

You must be using the 'auto' option for resConfig. 'auto' has been deprecated from the standard build, and is not supported in the bundle (the warning probably got lost in the logs after the error popped up):

android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        resConfigs "auto"
    }
}

Non-'auto' resConfigs are still supported in the bundle, so just specify which languages you would like to keep, as described in the documentation:

android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        resConfigs "en", "fr"
    }
}

Comment: Why do you say it's not supported? And why would that impact Google sign in?